# livereload rails 7 and incorrect (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mime-types, livereload, ruby-on-rails-7, x-content-type-options

I use gems :

```
gem 'guard'
gem 'guard-livereload', require: false
gem 'rack-livereload'
gem 'rb-fsevent',       require: false
```

and execute `bundle exec guard` like in Rails 6 (there is no problem) but with my rails 7 app, I have an error when I save CSS and trying relaod it :

> Resource at 'http://localhost:3000/seances' was blocked due to incorrect MIME type ('text/html') incorrect (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

All my css are remove, but new css is not apply.

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is sometimes a problem with the default dev rails configuration of config.assets.digest, try setting it to false in config/development.rb

```
config.assets.digest = false
```

Source: https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload/issues/193

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the your web server which is serving up your css resource includes the correct mime type in the Content-type header (should be text/css, not text/html)

Comment: how do you do this with rails 7?